# modify all html of a certain class

Tags: jquery

i have this

```
<p class="comment_date" title="a">c</p>
<p class="comment_date" title="b">b</p>
```

i want put the title in the html of any element. so i try with this:

```
$(".comment_date").html($('.comment_date').attr("title"));
```

But it's wrong

how i can do it?

thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
$('.comment_date').each(function() {
    $(this).html( $(this).attr('title') );
});
```

I *think* this should do it - let me know if that isn't what you're looking for.

It may be worth it to check if the `title` attribute length is `>0`. It's best to use `.each` for cases such as this, otherwise you're setting something to the combined value of multiple elements' values if you don't use `.each`.

Comment: Didn't work for me. doesn't replaceWith() replace the whole tag and everything?

Comment: -1 As this actually removes the `<p>` tags instead of just setting value of the title as content

Answer (score 3):

This should do it

```
$(".comment_date").each(function(i,e) {
  var x = $(e);
  x.html(x.attr("title"));
});
```

Comment: wouldn't that reference the counter and not the element itself?

Comment: lmao... we posted at the same time... sorry. +1 for same answer. haha

Answer (score 1):

```
try this:

$(".comment_date").each(function() {
    var cd = $(this);
    cd.html(cd.attr("title"));
});
```