# jQuery script only affects first DIV in my page?

Tags: jquery

I am new in jQuery, and can't seem to get the following code to work to my liking:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $.fn.digits = function(text){
                $(this).text(text.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") + '€' );
            };
            var tempText = $.trim($("#price").text());
            tempText = tempText.substr(0, parseInt(tempText.length) );
            $("#price").digits(tempText);
        });
</script>
```

It's should convert numbers in all #price divs into comma seperated currency versions:

1000000 = 1,000,000€

This works fine for the fist instance of #price on a page, but if the same ID appears more than one time on the same page, the rest are not being formatted by the script.

I found out that DIV's mus be unique, so i tried to change then to classes in stead (#price to .price) which does the trick, but now creates a new problem. Now all instances of the .price are shown in every instance of the .price - if that makes sense.

Let's say i have .price 3 times in one page:

Example 1 (.price): 200000

Example 2 (.price): 250000

Example 3 (.price): 300000

Should show:

200,000€

250,000€

300,000€

In stead it gives me:

200,000€ 250,000€ 300,000€

200,000€ 250,000€ 300,000€

200,000€ 250,000€ 300,000€

Why is that, and how do i fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you also post the relative HTML?  Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [modify all html of a certain class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797055/modify-all-html-of-a-certain-class)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852452/how-to-select-first-child-with-jquery

Comment: Id is unique in page so it only work for first matching ID. please use class selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to affect multiple elements use class referencing rather than divs.

change this line

```
$("#price").digits(tempText);
```

to

```
$(".price").digits(tempText);
```

since classes are used for collection of elements and divs are used to reference only one item at a time... so it fetches the first div only.

and remember when using $('.price') you have to use a loop rather.. since they are many of them.. so your code becomes

```
$.each('.price', function(o, v){
   var tempText = $.trim($(this).text());
   tempText = tempText.substr(0, parseInt(tempText.length) );
   $(this).digits(tempText);
});
```

all things being equal, this should work...